# Combining multiple cell values on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Is there any way in Google Sheets to automatically change cells from the current format to intended format like in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({"♦"&A1:A&"♠", B1:B&", "}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", 0))), 
 "♦")), "♠")), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Comment: @player0 i have 6k rows. This gives me error `Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.`. Is there a way to overcome this limit and modify this formula to handle large data?

Comment: here's my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169246/combine-duplicate-rows-in-column-as-comma-separated-values-google-query/65182833?noredirect=1#comment115236664_65182833).

Comment: @sifar it depends on your dataset... https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187342/5632629