# Combining rows based on IDs on 2 columns Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have data that looks like this:

[image: input]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: output]

Formula ideas?
Thanks!
Maria

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi @player0, I think OP means combining rows based on ids from 2 columns. A bit similar to your [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169246/combine-duplicate-rows-in-column-as-comma-separated-values-google-query) but added onto another column instead on the same cell. I edited the post to show what I meant. The title is misleading I believe

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"×"&B2:B, 
 TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({"×"&C2:D}),,9^9))), 
 TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:D),,9^9)))}, 
 "select Col1, max(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),, 9^9)), "×")))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant as always.